# How to disable Chrome data saver in crosswalk webview?

Tags: crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

How do I disable Chrome's "data saver" in crosswalk webview?

During development of cordova/ionic app it is massively interfering because it prevents live-reload-injected CSS after about 20-30 seconds.

Comment: I'm the technical lead for the Chrome Data Saver product. As far as I know, Crosstalk Webview should not be using Chrome's Data Saver. Can you provide some details on what exactly you're seeing and a way for us to test on our end? Thanks!

Comment: @mdwelsh To test, start a remote-debugging session (chrome://inspect) of an ionic 2 app (2.0.0-rc.3) that uses [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) (2.1.0). Warning bar appears on the "Network" tab of Chrome debugger.

Comment: I'm also getting the same warning bar in a non ionic-based cordova app.  Data Saver is disabled in Chrome settings.  Connections to my API server aren't working (starting with the first connection made, they go into "stalled" state and never actually start talking to the server).